# Map local path to an online python compiler

Tags: python

I am using this online tool to run my python script : 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

The code I am trying to execute is

```
text_file = open('D:\\file.txt', 'r')
print(text_file.readlines())
```

As I am using an online compiler I am unable to locate the directory where the "file.txt" file should be placed. For the time being it is in the directory(D:\file.txt).

Please if someone can help me out with this problem...

Comment: Which online compiler are you using ?

Comment: Are you actually uploading the file? It might just be in s the same directory, i.e. 'file.txt'. However you'll have to read the documentation for whichever online compiler you're using - we can't help you without knowing that.

Comment: "https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/"

Comment: This is the online compiler I am using.

Comment: Unless you can upload the file on the platform you are using, that won't work. If the the content is not too large, just copy and paste it as a triple quote string. `file_content = """ .... """`

Comment: Assuming that you are using some kind of an online interpreter, you can't access files placed on your local computer this way. If it's an online interpreter (what you have referred to as 'Compiler'), it runs on another remote computer on the internet. So if you are going to access files this way inside your code, your file 'file.txt' should be placed inside that remote computer that your code runs on.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.